# Passing a checkbox's "checked" from a JSO to another

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, checkbox, forward

I'm a beginner in Java EE, I am trying to pass a checkbox's "checked" from a JSO to another, here is how it works :

**The "From" JSP :**

I am forwarding a request to a BookEdit.java servlet through an "Edit" link :

```
<td><a href="./BookEdit?author=<%= bookData.getBookList().get(i).getAuthor() %>&title=<%= bookData.getBookList().get(i).getTitle() %>&availabe=<%= bookData.getBookList().get(i).isAvailable() %>">Edit</a></td>
```

Which generates links like : `http://localhost:8080/LibraryWeb/BookEdit?author=H.P.%20Lovecraft&title=Call%20of%20Cthulhu&availabe=true`

The servlet simply forwards the request to the second JSP through its doGet()

**The "To" JSP :**

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gestion de bibliothèque - Edition de livres</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 align="center">Gestionnaire de bibliothèque</h1>
    <hr width="50%">
    <h3 align="center">Edition de livre</h3>

    <form method=post action=./BookEdit>
        <table align=center border=1px>
            <tr>
                <td>Author : </td>
                <td><input type=text name="author" size=20 maxlength=200 value="<%= request.getParameter("author") %>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Title : </td>
                <td><input type=text name="title" size=20 maxlength=200 value="<%= request.getParameter("title") %>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Available : </td>
                <td>
                    <% if (request.getParameter("available") == "true") { %>
                        <input name="available" value="true" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                    <% }
                    else { %>
                        <input name="available" value="false" type="checkbox">
                    <% } %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

The problem is, the checkbox on the second JSP is always unchecked, even if the "available" parameter has a "true" value. So what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution : I simply replaced the forwarding using a link with a form. But I would still like to know why the link approach didn't work.